# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a defination for 'Browser' in nopcommerce 4.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reference, httprequest, nopcommerce, asp.net-core-2.2

I am getting the title error. Here are the full error shows

**'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Browser' and no accessible extension method 'Browser' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Now, this error shows me when I write the code for check the site is working in **computer** or **mobile**.

I try to give the reference also for `HTTPRequest` but I didn't find in `nuget package`

Here is my controller code,

```
public ActionResult MobileBrowser()
{
    var browser = Request.Browser;
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase myBrowserCaps = browser;
    if (((System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "mob";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "web";
    }
    return PartialView();
}
```

Now, I get the **redline** in `var browser = Request.Browser;`, `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase myBrowserCaps = browser;` and `if (((System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice)`

Answer (score 0):

In nopCommerce they are providing that site used in a mobile device or not using the below service

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Get a value indicating whether the request is made by mobile device
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual bool IsMobileDevice()
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext == null)
            return false;

        //we put required logic in try-catch block
        //more info: https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/17711/unhandled-exception-request-is-not-available-in-this-context.aspx
        try
        {
            //we don't parse browscap library here
            //in 99% of cases it's enough to use the approach suggested by http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

            var userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.UserAgent].ToString();
            var mobile = _firstMobileDeviceRegex.IsMatch(userAgent) || _secondMobileDeviceRegex.IsMatch(userAgent.Substring(0, 4));
            return mobile;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Or instead of request browser, you can use this

```
var userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.UserAgent].ToString();
```

So this will sure helpful

Hope this will be helpful to you

Thank you

Comment: can you show me how can I implement this code in controller. Because I am tried at that time it shows me error i.e. **Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.**

Here is my controller code : **var mobileDevice = _userAgentHelper.IsMobileDevice();**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

1. **Without Injection**: Controller has Request object which is HttpRequest type it contains IHeaderDictionary type Header from where you will have browser information.

```
    public class UploadFileController : Controller
           {
                [HttpGet]
                public IActionResult Photo()
                {
                      var brows = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

                      return View();
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public IActionResult Photo(UserViewModel userViewModel)
                {
                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                        }
                     return View(userViewModel);
               }
          }
```

2. **IHttpContextAccessor Inject in controller**: 
   You need to add singleton service of the type specified in Startup class, Configuration method  `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`. Now you are ready to inject in controller -

```
     public class UploadFileController : Controller
            {
                private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
                public UploadFileController(IHttpContextAccessor  httpContext)
                {
                    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContext;
                }

                [HttpGet]
                public IActionResult Photo()
                {
                    var browser = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

                    return View();
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public IActionResult Photo(UserViewModel userViewModel)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                    }
                    return View(userViewModel);
                }
            }
```

3. **IHttpContextAccessor Inject in View**: If you want have browser information in the view you need to add in Startup class, Configuration method `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` and inject IHttpContextAccessor.

```
 @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

      @{
          ViewData["Title"] = "Upload Picture";

          var browser = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
      }
```

Comment: can you show me how can I implement this code in controller. Because I am tried at that time it shows me error i.e. Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration....'

Comment: Hi karan, I have edited my answer it may help you to solve your problem.